# Problem in Accessing third-party cookies from browser when the laravel project is uploaded on a shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, shared-hosting, setcookie

I created a two simple website in a shared hosting where one can create cookies and another one where it can supposedly get that created cookie, although the first one is creating the cookie the second website cannot get the corresponding data of that cookie. Both website are subdomains [image: name]

**website 1 to create cookie**

```
public function setCookie(Request $request) {
  $minutes = 60;
  $response = new Response('Created Cookie');
  $response->withCookie(cookie('name', 'userName', $minutes));
  return $response;
}
```

**website 2 to get cookie**

```
public function getCookie(Request $request) {
  $value = $request->cookie('name');
  echo $value;
}
```

I've tried change the value in $request->cookie('name') and change the name to 'laravel_session' just to check if its working and when I tried that, I could get the data of that cookie. I'm not really sure why its not working. Thank you

Comment: Laravel encrypts cookies by default. You need to create un-encrypted cookie to handle the issue. Follow this guide: https://gist.github.com/JacobBennett/15558410de2a394373ac

Answer (score 1):

If both of these websites have a different subdomain, then the browser by default prevents access to another website's cookies for security reasons.

You can allow website 2 to get website 1's cookies by adding the following HTTP headers inside website 1:

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://website2.example.com");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
```

of course, change `http://website2.example.com` to your website 2's domain.

Comment: Hello, Thank you but I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with using headers, so I added it in the middleware and called it in the route, although the cookie is still being made, the website 1&2 couldn't get the content of the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel encrypts cookies by default. You need to create shared un-encrypted cookie to handle the issue. Follow this guide: https://gist.github.com/JacobBennett/15558410de2a394373ac

Comment: Hello, Thank you I did what's in the guide and the content is now unencrypted and I can see that both of my subdomain is now under the domain which wasn't before https://imgur.com/5ZHo9Ul , but I couldn't get the cookie from the website 1 to the website 2, do I need to do this on both website or just the website 1? Thank you

Comment: Yes. You need to put the shared_cookie inside the $except array in all subdomains that you wish them to share cookies. Then you can access them using the: $request->cookie('name');